# no matching manifest for windows/amd64 docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, deployment, visual-studio-code

```
PS C:\Users\Mohit\Desktop\Zapp_labs\user_login_edesy> docker build -t nodejs-app-login:latest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  16.37MB
Step 1/6 : FROM node:9-slim
9-slim: Pulling from library/node
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.17763 in the manifest list entries
```

I am using Windows 10 installed docker please help !!!!!

Comment: Please describe your docker host. Is this a Windows server or desktop? Is it in Windows or Linux mode (in the whale icon on the notification panel)? Are you building a Windows or Linux application?

Comment: Please can you add some more detail, and what debugging steps you have already attemped. Also Welcome here :)